# JSON conversion

Tags: jquery, json

I'm fetching data and then serializing it to JSON string on server side and then passing it to the client side.
Assuming data I got on client side is JSON string, how can I iterate through JSON to create HTML table on client side ?

Comment: What code have your tried so far?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around to do this. Question is far too broad as it currently stands. If you have a specific code problem please show that code and update question with a proper problem description

Comment: I've tried using json.parse but it gives syntax error

Comment: Suppose I'm getting data in this format: var jsonString = [{"Id":"10","Name":"aaaaa"},{"Id":"1","Name":"nnnn"}]; , how  can I iterate through this value to convert in html table?

Answer (score 1):

**(Edited. supposing your table has an id="myTable" you can append your items[Id,Nombre] as described in the iteration block)**

You have not specified how receive data, but assuming that you receive after a jquery ajax request. This could be an example of how to iterate over the JSON.

First, Parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText)`

javascript block to be executed at the client side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $("#YourFormID").attr('action'),
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $("#YourFormID").serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(objeto) {
  },
  complete: function(response) {
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // Parse the JSON received
    jSONResp = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);     
    // If your expected list is called 'myList'
    if ('myList' in jSONResp) {

        // If your <table> does not exists, you can create it at this time, within an existing element (someContainer):
        $("#someContainer").append('<table id="myTable"><tr><td>ID</td><td><td>Name</td></tr></table>');

        for (var i=0; i<jSONResp.myList.length; i++) {
            var item = jSONResp.myList[i];
            // Append a new <tr> with the current item data to the table
            $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+item["Id"]+'</td><td>'+item["Name"]+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
  },
  error: function(objeto, quepaso, otroobj){
    alert("ERROR: "+quepaso);
  }
});
```

And the response. posible php script from the server side.

```
<?PHP
$data = /** whatever you're serializing, array of items etc **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**(sorry, I can't add comments yet, only responses)**

Comment: `data: $("#YourFormID").serialize(),` — Don't do that without correctly setting your content type request header.

Comment: `jSONResp = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText); ` — That won't work. `response` will be either the text of the response or the JS data structure created from parsing the response as if it were JSON (depending on what sort of data the content-type response header says it is).

Comment: Right, (Edited) I have added a bit more, including the possible server response with a content-type. I have coded these scripts in some our projects and they work.

Comment: `jSONResp = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);` still won't work as `responseText` is unlikely to be defined or contain JSON (unless you plan to encode JSON and then put it on an array before you encode that array as JSON (where you have /** whatever you're serializing, array of items etc **/) which would be bizarre.